# Meeting all Laravel 6.2 suggestions

Tags: php, laravel

I am installing laravel 6.2 and i wish to heed to all suggestions laravel throws me when i create a new application. Without even installing a third party package, laravel suggests installing a lot of things some that look super important to ignore. here is my installation log

```
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotat
on loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one ro
ter or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expr
ssion matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts suggests installing psr/event-dispatcher
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support in
ernationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern cr
pto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium exte
sion for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for
se with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting
UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing paragonie/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for us
 with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for
enerating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\
uid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages
to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log message
 to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending
og messages to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an
MQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to
 MongoDB server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messag
s to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages
to a MongoDB server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log
essages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log
essages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages
to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages
to an Elastic Search server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to
se S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to
se S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use
indows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem
adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (All
ws you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to
se Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use S
TP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use
WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to
use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to us
 Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you
o use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS
ueue driver, DynamoDb failed job storage and SES mail driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns
and drop SQLite columns (^2.6).)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-memcached (Required to use the memcac
e cache driver.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-pcntl (Required to use all features o
 the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-posix (Required to use all features o
 the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-redis (Required to use the Redis cach
 and queue drivers.)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Ma
lgun mail driver and the ping methods on schedules (^6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to u
e the Flysystem S3 driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required
to use the Flysystem cache (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use th
 Flysystem SFTP driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing moontoast/math (Required to use ordered U
IDs (^1.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beans
alk queue driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing psr/http-message (Required to allow Stora
e::put to accept a StreamInterface (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use
the Pusher broadcast driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/cache (Required to PSR-6 cache br
dge (^4.3.4).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required
to use PSR-7 bridging features (^1.2).)
laravel/framework suggests installing wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (Required to
use Postmark mail driver (^3.0).)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes Psy
H a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite t
 work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-posix (If you have PCNTL, you'll want the POS
X extension as well.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation.
ou'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit
)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
facade/ignition suggests installing laravel/telescope (^2.0)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
sebastian/environment suggests installing ext-posix (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.7.2)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0.0)
Generating optimized autoload files
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> @php artisan key:generate --ansi
←[32mApplication key set successfully.←[39m
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: ←[32mfacade/ignition←[39m
Discovered Package: ←[32mfideloper/proxy←[39m
Discovered Package: ←[32mlaravel/tinker←[39m
Discovered Package: ←[32mnesbot/carbon←[39m
Discovered Package: ←[32mnunomaduro/collision←[39m
←[32mPackage manifest generated successfully.←[39m
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

There are two things i am unsure about. How do i go about instaling the symphony suggestions and is there a complete list of all packages laravel suggests you install?.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best way is to work out what each additional package does and only then decide if you want it in the site you are building

Comment: Why install `doctrine/couchdb` if you don't use CouchDB? (Those are not suggestions by Laravel, but by the individual packages. I'd only install them if you need them)

Comment: You could probably parse that output to create some sort of Frankenstein's monster of project dependencies, but you'd most likely end up with a very bloated vendor folder full of unused libraries. I don't know if a huge autoload file slows down an application, but it just might.

Comment: Is there a way this suggestions can be switched off?

Comment: You can use `--no-suggest` to hide suggestions when installing/updating. https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore these suggestions, in my experience, you should eliminate any extra package that has no need on your system since this will cause more performance issues, compatibility issues, maintenance issues, security issue

You can use  `--no-suggest` to disable suggestions when installing/updating.